# Changing Process Name using Shell for nagios monitoring with check_procs

Tags: python, shell, ubuntu, process, nagios

I have a python script to start a process which I want to monitor using Nagios. When I run that script and perform `ps -ef` on my ubuntu EC2 instance, it shows process as `python <filename>.py --arguments`. For Nagios to monitor that process using check_procs, we need to supply process name. Here process name becomes 'python'.

```
/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_procs -C python
```

It returns the output that one python process is running. This is fine when I'm running one python process. But If I'm running multiple python scripts and monitor only few, then I have to give that particular process name. If in the above command, I give python script name, it throws an error. So I want to mask whole `python <filename>.py --arguments` to some other name so that while performing check_procs, I can give that new name.

If anyone have any idea, please let me know. I have checked other stackoverflow questions which suggest changing python process name using setproctitle but I want to perform it using shell.

Regards,

Sanket

Comment: You want to use a shell to start a Python script, which in turn will start another process. However, you want the shell to start that original Python process with a different process name and arguments to the ones you're actually providing to the shell. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes..This is what I exactly want to achieve !!

Comment: check_procs is more clever than just looking at the ps 'command' output.  It can already detect the name if you use #! lines in your python and execute them directly.  [Totally not documented in the man page :( ].  See my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10232406/117714

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the check_procs command to look at arguments, which includes the module name. The following command will let you know if the python module 'module.py' is running.

```
/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_procs -c 1:1 -a module.py -C python
```

The -c argument lets you set the critical range. 1:1 will trigger a critical status if there is more or less than 1 process that matches running.

The -a argument will filter based on processes that contain the args 'module.py' (change it to the name of the module you want to monitor)

The -C argument will make sure that the process is a python process

If you need help figuring out how to create the service definition, I had to figure that out too. Just let me know.

REFERENCE:
check_procs plugin manpage
http://nagiosplugins.org/man/check_procs

Answer (score 2):

You [can't change the process name](http://bugs.python.org/issue5672) from pure Python, although you can use a wrapper (for example, written in C) to do so.

However, what you should do instead is making your program a daemon, and using a pidfile. Have a look at the [python Daemon API](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3143/) and its implementation [python-daemon](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-daemon).

Comment: this is a much better way to identify the correct process - if you're not already writing a PID file then this is just one of the many reasons you should be.

Answer (score 1):

check_procs already handles this situation.

check_procs can tell the difference between scripts launched as an argument to the interpreter vs jobs run directly a hashbang interpreter.  Even though both of these look the same in the ps output!!  The latter case will not be listed in `check_procs -C python`!

If you run your scripts explicitly via python: `python <filename.py>`, then you can monitor them with the `check_procs -C python -a filename.py`.

If you put `#!/usr/bin/python` in your scripts and run them as `./filename.py`, then you can monitor with `check_procs -C filename.py`.

Example command line session showing this behavior:

```
#make test.py directly executable.  See code below
$ chmod a+x test.py

#launch via python explicitly:
$ /usr/bin/python ./test.py &
[1] 27094
$ check_procs -C python && check_procs -C test.py && check_procs -a test.py
PROCS OK: 1 process with command name 'python'
PROCS OK: 0 processes with command name 'test.py'
PROCS OK: 1 process with args 'test.py'

#launch via python implicitly
$ ./test.py &
[2] 27134
$ check_procs -C python && check_procs -C test.py && check_procs -a test.py
PROCS OK: 1 process with command name 'python'
PROCS OK: 1 process with command name 'test.py'
PROCS OK: 2 processes with args 'test.py'

#PS 'COMMAND' output looks the same
$ ps 27094 27134
  PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
27094 pts/6    S      0:00 /usr/bin/python ./test.py
27134 pts/6    S      0:00 /usr/bin/python ./test.py

#kill the explicit test
$ kill 27094 
[1]  - terminated  /usr/bin/python ./test.py                                                                           
$ check_procs -C python && check_procs -C test.py && check_procs -a test.py
PROCS OK: 0 processes with command name 'python'
PROCS OK: 1 process with command name 'test.py'
PROCS OK: 1 process with args 'test.py'

#kill the implicit test
$ kill 27134
[2]  + terminated  ./test.py                                                                                           
$ check_procs -C python && check_procs -C test.py && check_procs -a test.py
PROCS OK: 0 processes with command name 'python'
PROCS OK: 0 processes with command name 'test.py'
PROCS OK: 0 processes with args 'test.py'
```

test.py is a python script that sleeps for 2 minutes.  It is chmod +x and has a hashbang `#!` line invoking /usr/bin/python.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import time
time.sleep(120)
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a pid file and use that file for the process lookup with nagios.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not saying this is the best solution (it wouldn't scale well at all), but you can create a symbolic link to the `python` command and execute your script using this link.  e.g.

```
ln -s `which python` ~/mypython
~/mypython myscript.py
```

Scripts launched using the link should show up as `mypython` in `ps`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [subprocess.Popen](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html?highlight=subprocess#popen-constructor) to change the executable name, but you'd have to use a wrapper script (or some weird fork magic).  The following code causes `ps` to list the executable as `kwyjibo /tmp/test.py` instead of `/usr/bin/python /tmp/test.py`:

```
import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen(['kwyjibo', '/tmp/test.py'], executable='/usr/bin/python')
```